# Splitting review audio files into speech segments (sentences/phrases)

Tags: audio, split, speech-recognition, speech

**Context:** I have many review audio files. In these files there is a person speaking about some product and in most of them there is also a background music.

**Problem:** I need to split each file into speech segments(sentences/phrases). In addition, I would like some unsupervised method. 
    Or some supervised where the input are samples of music, mute, and speech audio because I have a dataset with this kind of samples. *P.S: I don't need to understand what they are saying*

This is not my focus for now, then the approach doesn't need to be perfect or something like that, no problem if some of them are wrong after processing.

I have read some papers about this problem but for now I haven't found any tool to do that in this context.

Is there some tool and/or code that could help me in this problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a proper place to ask for a software recommendations. I answered you on the same question on  Quora

Comment: before posting, I checked many questions like that here... then I supposed that was ok my question. Just now I realized that I already got an answer there and here, thanks :)

Comment: Did you find out any tool to do this? Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: @BSharerApp-ShareBooks Actually it wasn't a tool, but I found this paper **(An Open-source State-of-the-art Toolbox for Broadcast News Diarization)**[https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1fd3/4ce04227c0970c995dbf41e0280e57d98185.pdf]. They developed a toolbox and put it available online. 
In my case, I could use it to do my task

Comment: Actually, I found a good answer (https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/neSEDMBP62w). webrtcvad (https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad) is very useful and seems working really nicely.